# C# Does not accept the expected number of console inputs

Tags: c#

```
double userheight;
double userweight;

double calculateBMI(double weight, double height)
{
return weight / (height \* height);
}

Console.Write("Insert your height: ");
userheight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Read());

Console.WriteLine("Insert your weight: ");
userweight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Read());

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: "+calculateBMI(userweight, userheight ));
```

It simply lets me input the value for userheight but not userweight. After I input userheight it simply calculates the function without using userweight. I dont know why the Console.read(); isn't working

Comment: You probably want `Console.ReadLine` instead of `Read`to enter multiple values

Comment: `Console.Read` reads a single character at a time. The second `Console.Read` is reading the extra characters you typed the first time.

Comment: Also, have a look into `double.TryParse` which you might want to prefer over `Convert.ToDouble` and that the BMI as a measure is widely accepted to be outdated (if this happens to be more than an example to just have _something_ to implement).

Answer (score 2):

`Console.Read` reads **a single character**. So if you wanted to enter - say - 50 for your height, you'd get *two* instead of *one* key-strokes, one for `5` and one for `0`. So the `5` goes to your height, while the `0` goes to your weight.

If you want to read an entire line instead of a single character, use `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
Console.Write("Insert your height: ");
userheight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Insert your weight: ");
userweight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Btw.: You should also handle input-errors, like user doesn't type a valid number at all or decimals are in wrong format (point instead of comma for instance). So better use `TryParse` instead of `ToDouble`:

```
Console.Write("Insert your height: ");
if(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userHeight))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code, the crucial are

- `\*` which doesn't compile in `calculateBMI`
- `Read` (single character) instead of `ReadLine` (entire string)

Let's design from scratch and start from extracting input as a method:

```
private static double ReadDouble(string prompt) {
  // We keep asking user
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prompt))
      Console.Write(prompt);

    // Note ReadLine instead of Read
    if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var result))
      return result; // until user provides a valid floating point value

    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid floating point value, please, try again.");
  }
}
```

Then having extracted `calculateBMI`

```
// static: we don't want instance - this - here
private static calculateBMI(double weight, double height)
{
  return weight / (height * height);
}
```

You can put the final routine like this:

```
double userHeight = ReadDouble("Insert your height: ");
double userWeight = ReadDouble("Insert your weight: ");

double bmi = calculateBMI(userWeight, userHeight);

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine($"Your BMI is: {bmi}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Console.ReadLine()` to fetch user input and follow it up with `Console.ReadLine();` to to prevent closing of the Console Window Automatically.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        double userheight;
        double userweight;

        Console.Write("Insert your height: ");
        userheight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Insert your weight: ");
        userweight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is: " + CalculateBMI(userweight, userheight));

        Console.ReadLine(); // This line is added to prevent the console window from closing immediately
    }

    static double CalculateBMI(double weight, double height)
    {
        return weight / (height * height);
    }
}
```

> Refer the working .netFiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQ1GTK).

Comment: _"to prevent closing of the Console Window Automatically."_ - that can actually be configured in Visual Studio (and I believe in Rider, too), so you don't need that extra ReadLine().

Comment: Thanks, I've added it just as a precaution.